# upload image data from csv file in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, csv

For a **shopping site**, I need to add product via file upload.

I have returned the data entered from **csv** as array. But now I need the images too. But in Csv only the image names will be given. 
I need  the image content in db. My images are stored as long blob data.

How can I get the image content?

Comment: no idea from none... :'(